# How do I add the 'Grand Total'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I add the 'Grand Total' to my query? I have tried a few things to get where I am now, but I don't know why the total isn't popping up.

```
USE [2060OtherFunctionsYouShouldKnow]
SELECT COALESCE(PurchaseDate,'GrandTotal') AS PurchaseDate
    ,Sum(PurchaseAmt) AS [Summarized Purchase Amt]
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY PurchaseDate
ORDER BY PurchaseDate
```

this is my results so far
[image]

Any help I get would be great!

Comment: SELECT only returns rows that actually exist. So if there aren't any rows where PurchaseDate is null then 'Grand Total' won't be displayed - and if it is displayed it will be the sum of the rows where PurchaseDate is null.  Which database are you using?

Comment: You say you want to add "Grant Total" to your query - but what are you actually doing with the query results?  It would not be a usual way to get a grand total showing on a report, or perhaps your web page, for example, by having all of the detail rows and then another row at the end of the resultset for "Grand Total" .... perhaps if you explain what you will do with your query results, then someone can guide you in the best way to implement

Comment: If you want to add a GrandTotal line to the query results use a UNION

Comment: Look into `rollup()`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `ROLLUP`**, although the syntax in the other answer is deprecated:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(PurchaseDate,'GrandTotal') AS PurchaseDate
    ,Sum(PurchaseAmt) AS [Summarized Purchase Amt]
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PurchaseDate)
ORDER BY PurchaseDate;
```

Another option, more useful with lots of grouping columns, is to **use `GROUPING SETS`**

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(PurchaseDate,'GrandTotal') AS PurchaseDate
    ,Sum(PurchaseAmt) AS [Summarized Purchase Amt]
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
    (PurchaseDate),
    ( )
)
ORDER BY PurchaseDate;
```

If `PurchaseDate` is nullable, you can use **the `GROUPING` function** instead of `ISNULL`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(PurchaseDate) = 0 THEN PurchaseDate ELSE 'GrandTotal' END AS PurchaseDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the rows for you summarized data and then add a Grand Total row using a UNION:

```
SELECT PurchaseDate, Sum(PurchaseAmt) AS [Summarized Purchase Amt]
FROM tPurchaseItem
GROUP BY PurchaseDate
ORDER BY PurchaseDate;
UNION
SELECT "Grand Total" AS PurchaseDate, Sum(PurchaseAmt) AS [Summarized Purchase Amt]
FROM tPurchaseItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing `with rollup`

```
select Coalesce(PurchaseDate,'GrandTotal') as PurchaseDate
  ,Sum(PurchaseAmt) as [Summarized Purchase Amt]
from tPurchaseItem
group by PurchaseDate
with rollup
order by PurchaseDate
```